# Error: Socket operation on non-socket

Tags: c, linux, shell, sockets, unix

```
if(serverSocket=socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0) < 0) {
     perror("Falhou a Ligacao ao socket");
     exit(1);
}

bzero((char *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strcpy(serv_addr.sun_path, UNIXSTR_PATH);
servlen = strlen(serv_addr.sun_path) + sizeof(serv_addr.sun_family);
if (bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, servlen) < 0){ 
     perror("error");
     exit(1);
}
```

Any idea why im getting this error at -"perror("Error") ; i got socket.h included

Comment: `=` need to be ``==`` in ``if`` statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong.  This will not assign serverSocket the return value.

```
if(serverSocket=socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0) < 0)
```

Just change the parenthesis to

```
if ((serverSocket = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
{
    perror("Falhou a Ligacao ao socket");
    exit(1);
}
```